# RestKit Using the same RKResponseDescriptors for multiple urls

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have two endpoints that return an user object. Instead of creating two RKResponseDescriptors is there a path pattern format that allows both to be used together.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *userResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"users"
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:userResponseDescriptor];

RKResponseDescriptor *userAuthResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"auth"
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:userAuthResponseDescriptor];
```

Is there a way to combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the path patterns you show in your code, no. There really isn't a lot of overhead to having 2 different response descriptors. They are separate responses. From a performance point of view you should not notice any difference.